# Transport Close on console log

Tags: node.js

I have 3 roads

```
//Roads
const signin = io.of('/signin');
const cancelOfferOrDemand = io.of("/cancel");
const disconnect = io.of("/disconnect");
```

The first two of them are working perfectly and logged the information sent.
The third prints me "transport close" instead of the information content that I send. In order to test and send those data I just have an html file where I just switch the server adress where to connect and the signal sent. So the data sent and the same in the three cases.

```
//------------------------------ SIGNIN ---------------------------------------//
signin.on('connection', function (socket, information) {

    const collection = client.db(dbName).collection('UserConnected');


    socket.on('new', async function(information) {
        console.log(information);
    });


});

//----------------------- CANCEL OFFER DEMAND --------------------------------//
cancelOfferOrDemand.on('connection', function (socket, information) {
    socket.on('cancel_demand', async function(information) {
        console.log("information");

    });
});


//------------------------------ DISCONNECT ----------------------------------//
disconnect.on('connection', function (socket, information) {
    socket.on('disconnect', async function (information) {
        console.log(information);
        });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter `information` from `socket.on('disconnect', function(information) { ... })` can only give you 3 response : `io server disconnect`, `io client disconnect`, `ping timeout`.

The information that you're printing is normally the second parameter. If you want to show the first one, make sure to change the name and check the reference inside of your `console.log()`. You should also do the same for the `connect` and `cancel_demand` event.

[Documentation event `connect`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99)
[Documentation event `disconnect`](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99)